# Problem simulating elastic collisions using simulation nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, physics, collision, simulation-nodes

So I have a question regarding simulation nodes and am hoping someone can help resolve my issue.

blender version: 3.6 (Stable)

I am creating a geo nodes setup that attempts to simulate perfectly elastic collisions in four particles. The particles must move inside a unit circle boundary and collide in a perfectly elastic fashion with the interior walls of the unit circle. As of posting this I have set up the velocity part (they move with a constant speed and direction when I click play on the timeline). I want the particles to have an initial 'Kick' as if they are projected from their initial positions and then after each timestep a constant distance is added.

I am calculating the reflected velocity vector by reflecting it around the normal vector at the collision point. I am only executing this calculation on the contition that the particle's current position exceeds 1 (if d > r) using a switch node. Though, illustrated by the gif (if i can post it here) you can see that once the particles reach the point that they should rebound, they do collide which is good but they dont carry on with the new velocity vector, as in they just stick there and dont bounce away with a new constant velocity after the collision.

PS. Once I get the rebound fixed, i intend to add a small deviation to the rebound vector direction so that the result is more chaotic (otherwise, if Angle of incidence = angle of reflection, then im pretty sure the particles will just trace out a circumscribed quadrilateral which is boring imo) so i guess it will no longer be perfect elastic collision but will mimic it.

I am certain I am missing something in my node set up or something in the implementation I have overlooked. I hope someone can help and thanks :)

https://youtu.be/HgWHkZQC8dM

Node setup below (or above depending on where I post this)

[image: The current incorrect simulated output of the particThe full node treeles]

[image: The simulation part]

[image: Full node tree]

Comment: Hi Ruben, unfortunately your node tree cannot be read, so please improve that. And i would recommend providing a blend file so people can check it out and don't have to rebuild it manually.

Comment: Hi, Ruben .. thanks for trying .. but until we can read your node-tree, we can't really figure out what's going on.. and personally I can't see the connection between your provided video and the rest of the problem as stated. Please edit to clarify, for complete strangers to your problem. Then we can re-open your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a circle, for which a collision detection is easier than for an ellipse. Then programming the collision resolution.

### Initialization

I'm spawning 33 points, all of them within 20 cm of the border (which will be a 1 m radius circle), so we don't have to wait for them to come closer to the circle, and without particle-particle collisions they are still likely to hit the border at an angle:

[image]

### Loop

The idea is to:

- Detect a collision (moving outside the boundary).
- Calculate when/where the collision happened.
- Evaluate the moment of collision.
- Evaluate the collision normal and reflected velocity from that normal.
- Calculate where the point should be now, after the collision happened.
- Update positions and velocities.

[image]

1. Scale velocity by $Δt$.
2. Add it to current point position.
3. Check if after such movement it would go beyond allowed zone (circle $r=1$).
4. If so, calculate how far it would cross the zone ($1 - $ distance from $<0, 0, 0>$).
5. Scale the velocity by the above length…
6. …And subtract it from position obtained in 2. This way position got clamped to the boundary.
7. Reflect velocity around the above position (because it's a circle, the position equals the normal).
8. Pass the reflected velocity as the new velocity to the Sim Out.
9. Scale reflected velocity by the length calculated in 4.
10. Add it to the position obtained in 6.

### Display

[image]

### Everything¹ Everywhere All at Once

[image]

¹- well, OK, I didn't code the particle-particle interactions, but already the setup got large. To draw the rest of the owl you need to, for each point, check if it collided with any other point, and if so, do the same logic. The "only" problem here is then, that a point can be caught between a rock and a hard place, it may simultaneously bounce from more than 1 point. In this case you could average resulting velocities. In order to program substeps, just put all the logic inside the loop in a custom group, and chain custom groups.

[image]

[image]

### Last Minute Thoughts

Consider multiplying the velocity by $<1, 1, 0>$ to flatten it on each frame.

Also consider how because the calculations are done on points, and $r = 0.01$ spheres are instanced on them, the actual boundary becomes $r = 1.01$ (and so for correctness, the circle at the end should be increased so that the spheres never intersect with it).